# Find a set of minimal elements in set $\langle \mathbb N\setminus\{0\},|\rangle$

Tags: relations, order-theory

We consider a relation $|$ on set $\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$

1. Find set of minimal elements in set $\langle \mathbb N\setminus\{0\},|\rangle$
2. Prove that in set $\langle \mathbb N\setminus\{0\},|\rangle$ there is no maximal element.

A minimal element of a subset S of some preordered set is defined dually as an element of S that is not greater than any other element in S. Same situation with maximal element.

Yes, | is divisibility.

For me, set of minimal elements is just {1} because every number greater than 1 is divided by 1 and to prove that there are no maximal elements in this set, then I'd take n∈N and show that n is not maximal element, it means that there exists element greater in |(divisibility) relation. For example 2n.
Or better proof is by assumption that there are maximal elements and came to contradiction?

Comment: Help us to help you. What does it mean "minimal element"? What does it mean "maximal element"? First, in general for a partial ordering, and then what could it mean if the ordering in particular is _divisibility_ ($\mid$)? Shortly, what are your thoughts and where do you seem  to have got stuck?

Comment: A minimal element of a subset S of some preordered set is defined dually as an element of S that is not greater than any other element in S. Same situation with maximal element. Yes, | is divisibility. For me, set of minimal elements is just {1} because every number greater than 1 is divided by 1 and to prove that there are no maximal elements in this set, then I'd assume that there are maximal elements and came to contradiction.

Comment: Your question is in danger of being closed, Xyz. You might avoid this outcome, if you edit your question to include what you have written in your comment.

Comment: Thank you so much <3 You've helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

(Converted from a previous comment, which the OP says was helpful.)

The argument that no $n$ can be a maximal element (because $n\mid 2n$ and $n\ne 2n$) is good.

The argument "$1$ is the minimal element because it divides all numbers" is a bit incomplete: what you said implies that no other number is minimal, but doesn't fully prove that $1$ is minimal. You should've added that the only divisor of $1$ is $1$ itself (which is the true meaning of "$1$ is minimal" here).

To see the difference better, consider the example $\langle\mathbb N\setminus\{0,1\},\mid\rangle$, where the set of minimal elements is... the set of all prime numbers. (Why?)